# SQLite Extensions exception: ManyToOne relationship destination must have Primary Key

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

You can see the error in title.
There are my table classes:

```
public class Cars : Table
{
    [NotNull]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Models)), NotNull]
    public int model_out_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Bodies)), NotNull]
    public int body_out_id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string vin { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4), NotNull]
    public int year { get; set; }
    [Indexed, NotNull]
    public long created_at { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.GetTimestamp();

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public Models Model { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public Bodies Body { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<CarGlasses> CarGlasses { get; set; }

    public Cars()
    {
    }
}

public class Models : TableLibrary
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int out_id { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Marks)), NotNull]
    public int mark_out_id { get; set; }
    [Indexed, NotNull]
    public int year_from { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public int? year_to { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead), Ignore]
    public Marks Mark { get; set; }

    public Models()
    {
    }
}
```

Error occurs here:

```
inst.GetChild(car, "Model");
```

`inst` is `SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection` instance

Everything worked fine when I used library as plain code, but now I added it as PCL reference. As you can see PrimaryKey exists in `Models` table. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my thread on xamarin forums. I've got solution there.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/288455